# MASM Assembly: Floating-Point Calculations

Tags: assembly, masm

I've been racking my brain for a couple days now and am still actively debugging.  I'm trying to compute the average of a couple of numbers and round the result up or down.  Here are the necessary variable declarations:

```
totalNum        DWORD   ?
sum         DWORD   ?   ; sum of numbers
avg         DWORD   ?
rem         DWORD   ?
decimal     REAL4   0.5
```

Code snippet:

```
; ********************
; * calculateAverage *
; ********************
mov eax, sum
mov ebx, totalNum
cdq
div ebx
mov avg, eax        ; save average
mov rem, edx        ; save remainder

mov eax, rem        ; divide divisor (totalNum) by remainder to round up/down
mov ebx, totalNum
cdq
div ebx

cmp eax, decimal    ; compare result to .5
jge roundUp     ; if >= .5, jump to roundUp
jmp endRoundUp

roundUp:            ; round up average
    add avg, 1
endRoundUp:

; ******************
; * displayResults *
; ******************
mov edx, OFFSET countText1  ; display total numbers entered
call WriteString
mov eax, totalNum
call    WriteDec
mov edx, OFFSET countText2
call WriteString
call    Crlf
mov edx, OFFSET sumText     ; display sum of numbers entered
call WriteString
mov eax, sum
call    WriteDec
call    Crlf

mov edx, OFFSET avgText     ; display rounded average of numbers entered
call WriteString
mov eax, avg
call    WriteDec
```

When I try to just display the value in *decimal*, I *mov eax, decimal* and get a 10-bit number.  The program computes the sum and total numbers correctly, and even computes the average correctly, but I cannot get it to round properly or display a floating point number.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `div` for your division; I believe `div` is an instruction that works on integer values, and you're doing floating point calculations. That's why you're getting the wrong result.

There's a few ways you can do floating point arithmetic on modern x86 CPUs:

- Using the [x87 floating point instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8087_instructions).
- There's all sorts of ways you can do it with [SIMD & SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#SIMD_instructions). I'm sure [AVX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) offers some solutions as well.

Comment: Hmmm, that's beyond what we're doing right now, but thanks for the div clarification.  A classmate provided a solution albeit not an elegant one.

Comment: @stef2dotoh If you're ever wondering how to do something in assembly, a good way to find out is to implement it in C++/C, then look at the compiler's disassembly. Just a tip :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use div with dword but you can't use it with real4, you have to use fdiv
However, I don't really recommend using eax when dealing with floating numbers because you can just use fild for integers and fld for decimals ( which is much easier )

Also the answer would be in st(0) which you'll need to print by call writefloat instead of call writedec

if you want to just display 0.5 you can always say

```
     fld decimal
   call writefloat
```